# Как получить ftp доступ к сайту на сервере, если есть ssh доступ к нему?

Tags: mysql, ssh, ftp

У меня есть ssh доступ (root) к Bitrix virtual machine, так понимаю к БД непосредственно. Как мне найти доступ к ftp?

Comment: "из коробки" ftp-доступ там не предусмотрен, но ssh позволяет делать всё то же самое, что и ftp, разница лишь в безопасности - ssh, в отличие от ftp, шифрует весь трафик от и к серверу

Comment: Существует протокол SFTP. По сути тот же FTP протокол работающий поверх SSH. Попробуйте с помощью FileZilla подключится к серверу с помощью протокола SFTP используя те же данные что и для SSH доступа.

Answer (score 1):

для монтирования каталога на сервере поверх *ssh* вы можете воспользоваться программой [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/).

но если пользуетесь каким-нибудь дистрибутивом операционной системы *gnu/linux*, возможно, более удобным средством будет программа *sshfs* из одноимённого пакета, присутствующего в репозиториях всех популярных дистрибутивов.

для начала создайте какой-нибудь пустой каталог в своём домашнем каталоге:

```
$ mkdir ~/какой-нибудь-каталог
```

затем можете монтировать любой каталог с *сервера*, куда у вас есть доступ по протоколу *ssh* под именем *пользователь*. например, домашний каталог этого *пользователя*

```
$ sshfs пользователь@сервер: ~/какой-нибудь-каталог
```

или корневой каталог *сервера*:

```
$ sshfs пользователь@сервер:/ ~/какой-нибудь-каталог
```

теперь любой программе, запущенной вами на вашей машине, будут доступны файлы и каталоги из примонтированного с *сервера* каталога:

```
$ ls ~/какой-нибудь-каталог
```

---

только не забывайте отмонтировать этот каталог после использования (и до нового монтирования в это же место):

```
$ fusermount -u ~/какой-нибудь-каталог
```