# Как открыть удалённый репозиторий по SSH в Git-GUI?

Tags: git, репозиторий

Собственно вопрос в том, как открыть в Git-GUI репозиторий, по SSH ?

Comment: [примонтируйте каталог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/445643/178576) и пользуйтесь его содержимым сколько влезет.

Comment: Гораздо удобнее сперва клонировать все к себе. Быстрее выйдет.